# In aws lambda(python), xpath cannot be used with selenium

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I am using AWS Lambda (python3.7) to perform web scraping. You can check the xpath of each element of the target website by using the developer tools in the Google Chrome browser on your local PC.
Even if I specify that xpath in Lambda, the following error will be output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    URL = "https://hogehogemy.com"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = "/opt/headless/headless-chromium"
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path="/opt/headless/chromedriver",
        options=options
    )

    browser.get(URL)
    id = browser.find_element_by_id("sender-email")
    id.send_keys("abc@example.com")
    password = browser.find_element_by_id("user-pass")
    password.send_keys("P@ssw0rd")
    login_button = browser.find_element_by_name("commit")
    login_button.click()
    sleep(5)
　　print(browser.page_source)
    xpath = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/div/main/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
    xpath = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/main/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
    browser.close()

Error details: [ERROR] NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
{
    "method": "xpath",
    "selector": "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/main/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"
}
```

When I tried to retrieve each element within Lambda, I was able to retrieve the name and id elements without any problems.
However, since the html source cannot be checked, it seems that the xpath cannot be specified either.

I ran "browser.page_source" as below. However, the problem may be that I cannot check the contents within the  tag that contains the element I want to reference.

Part of the result of 　print(browser.page_source)　　Below

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

result of    browser.find_elements()      Below

```
[]
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to get with xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Hi dude try to change value of XPATH from this:

> value="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/main/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"

to this:

> value='//*[@id="email-yui_3_17_2_1_1535471160468_3967-field"]'

sorry i can't test it bc your code doesn't work on my machine, but i had a lot of headache with XPATH's and get a lot of experience with that. Give me the feedback when you try

Comment: Is the value you specify XPath instead of fullXPath?

Comment: yes,  because it's more simple to debug than fullxp

like if you writing fullxp you need to check up all indexes of elemets

Comment: also try this, if the value above still getting error

Comment: /html/body//input[@id="email-yui_3_17_2_1_1535471160468_3967-field"]

Comment: but if this path doesn't work, dude unfortunately you need to write fullxp and check all indexes of html elements, debugging that SBS :( 
i went through that hell too

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Since this is a member-only website, I cannot provide the URL.